# Tell Laravels Validator where to look inside validation request array

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, validation, axios

If I validate my frontend form with axios by using the 'data' option it fails the validation in my backend laravel application.

```
axios.post('http://example.com/', {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  Accept: 'application/json',
  data: {
      email: 'email@email.com',
      password: '12345678',
    }
}).then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

So here I use the 'data' option to validate.

```
$request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string'
]);
```

Returns: 422 email is required password is required.

This is how the request gets formatted:

```
{Content-Type: "application/json", data: {email: "email@email.com", password: "12345678"}}
```

However if I submit the form this way with axios it validates and I'm logged in:

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'email': 'email@email.com',
'password': '12345678',
```

So my question is how to tell the validater to look inside the data object?

**EDIT 1:**
As requested `dd($request->attributes);` returns:

```
ParameterBag {#53
  #parameters: []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are adding `headers` as `data` in your `axios` request. your request should be like this:

```
const headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
};

let data: {
      email: 'email@email.com',
      password: '12345678',
    };

axios.post('http://example.com/',data, {headers:headers})
            .then( (response) => {
                //do the stuff
            })
            .catch( (error) => {
                // do the stuff
            });
```

`Note:` `axios` post function takes first `argument` as `url`, second as `data` and third as `config (headers etc)` while in your case you are mixing the header with data.
you can read more about [axios here](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, why would you need to add `data` in your axios?

If you're add `data`, then your validation should be as such:

```php
$request->validate([
    'data.email' => 'required|string|email',
    'data.password' => 'required|string',
]);
```

Comment: That returns Unauthorized. Not sure why.

Comment: Of course, since if you wrap the data send by axios with `data`, you need to get the email using `$request->get('data.email')`, not `$request->get('email')`. Btw, you mixed headers with data. Why? You don't need to wrap the data with `data`, just `axios.post('http://example.com/', {email: 'email@email.com', password: '12345678'})`